# ¿Cómo colocar entre comillas escapadas (\") una sección (una fecha) de un string en Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo un string de la siguiente forma:

```
"{:name=>\"Juan\", :date=>Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00, :title=>\"Lord\"}"
```

Quiero colocar la fecha entre comillas escapadas, es decir así:

```
"{:name=>\"Juan\", :date=>\"Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00\", :title=>\"Lord\"}"
```

¿Qué función o funciones de ruby puedo utilizar para transformar la parte del string anterior `:date=>Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00` en `:date=>\"Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00\"`?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo obtienes ese _string_? Parece un _hash_ válido con un formato específico en la fecha. Posiblemente sea mejor tratar el objeto antes de pasarlo a _string_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que estás trabajando con un *hash*, por lo que lo ideal sería trabajar con dicho *hash* **antes** de convertirlo a un *string*.

Sin embargo, si realmente deseas manipular ese *string* (tal como lo muestras), podrías utilizar expresiones regulares para detectar el texto al que deseas agregar las comillas, y hacer la sustitución del mismo texto con comillas; por ejemplo:

```
string = "{:name=>\"Juan\", :date=>Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00, :title=>\"Lord\"}"
#=> "{:name=>\"Juan\", :date=>Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00, :title=>\"Lord\"}"

date = string.match(/(?<=:date=>).*(?=,)/).to_s
#=> "Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00"

string.gsub(date, "\"#{date}\"")
#=> "{:name=>\"Juan\", :date=>\"Thu, 24 Aug 2017 03:30:03 UTC +00:00\", :title=>\"Lord\"}"
```

Comment: Efectivamente es un _hash_, fue guardado en un modelo de base de datos de esa forma. Por lo tanto, debo corregirlo como lo sugieres y luego prevenir que esto siga ocurriendo (y se guarde la date de una vez como un _string_). Una vez tenga la forma de _hash_ bien hecha puedo evaluarlo, se que se puede usar `eval(string)` pero no se si sepan alguno mas efectivo, no se si eval sea muy "costoso" por asi decirlo.

Comment: Debido a la estructura del texto me parece que tu única opción sería `eval`; no creo que sea tan costoso, pero tiene riesgo en caso que tu no tengas control sobre el contenido del _string_.